# Sub ItemsControl not showing pictures

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, collectionviewsource

I have an ListView which items contain a nested ItemsControl with some TextBlocks and an Image Control.

```
    private string _PicturePreview;
    public string PicturePreview { get => _PicturePreview; set => _PicturePreview = value; }
```

I have changed now the source of the ListView to an CollectionViewSource to group the Items. Everything renders nicely even the pictures in the ListView but for some reason the images in the nested ItemsControl are not loading anymore. When I switch back to the direct Binding without CollectionViewSource the images are loading properly.

Does someone know why?

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Sales" Source="{Binding Bestellungen}" >

        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>

            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="OrderTyp"/>

        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView Name="OrdersListView" Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Sales}}"            
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBestellung}" 
              AlternationCount="2" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
              >

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" >

                                        <Expander.Header>

                                            <DockPanel Background="#162270"  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=ActualWidth}" >
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="10" />


                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f2f2f2" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Order">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Belegnummer}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>


                    <GridViewColumn Header="Positionen" Width="800">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Positionen}" >
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Margin="0,0,10,5">

                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding PicturePreview, IsAsync=True}"/>
                                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">

                                                    <DockPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Stück: " FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Stück, StringFormat=N0}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                                                    </DockPanel>

                                                </StackPanel>

                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding VersandartNummer, Converter={StaticResource StringToBitmapConverter}}" MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="100"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>


                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: You mean `Binding Stück` works, but `Binding PicturePreview` doesn't?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, all Bindings work except PicturePreview. But only when I Use CollectionViewSource. When I bind the directly to the ListView it works fine.

Comment: And when you remove `IsAsync=True`? Shouldn't make a difference though...

Comment: @Clemens Wow now it works. Seems that CollectionViewSource doesn't get updated from Async tasks

Comment: @Clemens hmm ok I thought IsAsync moves the long loading in a background tast or something. It is okay to remove IsAsync for me.

Comment: Sure, the property getter is called on some kind of background thread. But is that really necessary? What's the type of the property? Does the getter consume a significant amount of time?

Comment: Your answer has helped. I have now removed all IsAsync from my Image Controls. Everything works fine now.

Comment: It would still be interesting to know why you thought IsAsync was necessary at all. As said, it isn't, unless you do something time-consuming in the property getter like e.g. synchronously loading a BitmapSource.

Comment: The ListView loads up to a few hundret items (orders) each order holds a List of Poisitions and for each position an image has to bee loaded from a websource. So  i wanted to make the list populate and let the images load in the background therefore i found the answer use IsAsync in antother thread.

Comment: You still don't tell how the property getter is implemented. If it just returns an Uri or string it won't consume any time. However, a BitmapFrame is created by built-in, automatic type conversion which already runs asynchronously. But that has nothing to do with an async Binding.

Comment: Added the Property. I must have misunderstood  IsAsync completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why exactly setting `IsAsync=True` would not work in conjunction with a CollectionViewSource, but it is pointless to set it anyway. The getter of your `PicturePreview` does not do anything time-consuming at all, so there is no need to call it asynchronously.

So just remove `IsAsync` from the Binding:

```
 <Image ... Source="{Binding PicturePreview}"/>
```

Note that the built-in type conversion from string to ImageSource creates a BitmapFrame that is already loaded asynchronously in case the URL string references a web resource.